# Creating a User with Multiple tables referencing the user

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble setting up a database which allows one user to either have their own database or directory which then stores info about them. So I have setup the database which stores login information about a user (user_id is an  AUTO_INCREMENT field). I would like to know what is the best way to setup a database or databases which allows one user to either link to many databases or a directory in MySQL.

Comment: You don't need to have database per user. You'll just need a primary key in your database and a foreign key to refer to specific user. Ps. Foreign key should be equal to primary key. You can read about database relationships, primary keys and foreign keys at google. ;)

Comment: @Yodism See i understand that its that when a user actually creates a database we need to create 3 unique tables which link back only to that user.  I want to find out which is the most "normalized" way to setup a database with multiple users linking to 3 tables or more tables which only are referenced back to them